# Windows phone 8.1 explorer unwanted mouseout event after holding finger for 1 second

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, windows-phone-8.1, mouseout

Upgrading from windows phone 8.0 to 8.1 (IE10 to IE11) broke my javascript based site.

These style settings are not enough to solve this problem.

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
ms-touch-action: none;
```

In this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdK2m/4)

if you keep your finger down more than 1 second before moving it, canvas gets mouseout event.

I want user to be able to move box even after keeping finger down for more than 1 second.

Comment: I think it is happening because now IE11 mobile supports `hover`.